# Editing rows in an interactive report using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I have been trying but I cannot edit rows. When I click the pencil icon near any row in the interactive report, I want it to take me to a separate page where I can edit the rows and update the table.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question seems to have little context, and to help you get answers to your question you should consider adding a printscreen that describes what your intended behavior is, as well as the _actual_ behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st Step**

- First create a blank page
- Add all those items to the page which are in the table
- Add source for each items as sql query i.e Use select statement with condition.
- Add an update button so that changes made are reflected to the table(You have 
  to use the update query by giving primary key of the table in where condition).

**2nd Step**

- Go to the interactive report page and edit the region
- Go to column link
- click on the pencil icon in the left side
- use your blank page no as the page to be redirected to
- below you will find some blank rows as Items and Values
- In Items select the item which you want to use in the where condition and value corresponding to it.
- Apply Changes.

DONE

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
1 - click on "Create Page"
2 - select "Form"
3 - select "Report with Form on Table"
4 - Fill the rest of the wizard
```

After you made this, apex create a report and when you clik on a pencil you can edit the data and save.

example: 
    https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145797:5

Comment: Yes but i want it to be done in interactive report only.

Comment: I have finally found the solution.

Comment: sorry i didn't knew about it as i am new here